# How to create a new Window in a new Thread with WinUI3 C++ unpackaged app?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winui-3, c++-coroutine

I didn't found any documentation about this in C++.
I used to use

```
winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::CreateNewView(); to create a new view in UWP.
```

But now, I don't know how to do:

```
co_await wil::resume_foreground(*viewResource->Dispatcher.get());

// Here is still previous thread
DebugHelper::OutputCurrentThreadInfo();

winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Window testWindow = 
winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Window();
co_await wil::resume_foreground(testWindow.DispatcherQueue());
auto rootFrame = Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame();
rootFrame.Navigate(winrt::xaml_typename<EditPage>());
testWindow.Content(rootFrame);
testWindow.Activate();
co_await winrt::resume_background();

co_await winrt::resume_background();
```

Please help me. thanks

Comment: User interfaces are typically single-threaded. If you need to work with UI components you need to do it in the UI thread.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But in UWP, ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::CreateNewView() will create a new thread for new window, so that even if the main window is destructed or crashed, the newly created window will still working...

Comment: There's a new AppWindow class (from Windows App SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/windowing/windowing-overview) that you should be able to use. See here also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/guides/windowing you can create a Windows using `Microsoft::UI::Windowing::AppWindow::Create().Show(true)` and you don't need another thread.

Comment: @SimonMourier then how do I set content to AppWindow? I only found ElementCompositionPreview::SetAppWindowContent, but this method only provided in Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting but not Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Hosting